Unable to Apply/Save Object Transforms
I have a peculiar problem, and I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered it, found a workaround? I'm building a ship, and it has about 70 component objects. At a recent point in the build, I decided to modify all the object origins to converge on the 3D cursor, which is set to the World origin.

However, once I saved this, I found that any further saves simply explode the model, meaning, now the origins, along with their respective objects, are scattered, every time I open the file fresh after rebooting the app.

I've already attempted to use Ctrl+A to apply all transforms individually, after snapping the origins of each to 3D cursor, setting the Transform orientations to global, the Transform Pivot Points to 3D cursor, and doing all this in Object Mode.
[Added: I should also note that I animated a cloth item, and added collision physics to the main hull around the time this glitch started occurring. Not entirely sure this is relevant, but it seems like it might be, since when I start the animation, the glitch reappears.]
I'm at the end of my knowledge rope here, so any assistance or novel ideas would be most welcome. Thanks in advance.
All the best,
PostModPag

I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Now that you've edited your question the answer is obvious! Delete any keyframes from your model and then set your origins first.
